# Is there anything like Turbolinks for node.js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, turbolinks

I really like using Turbolinks in Rails because it makes the page look faster to users. Is there a node.js alternative/version?

Comment: It sounds like a [SPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), there are plenty of frameworks out there.

Comment: @apneadiving thanks, that's very cool. care to submit it as answer?

Comment: Turbolinks is a node package, it works with rails, but there is no much on server-side to make it work. Check: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#installation-using-npm .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for something like [pjax](http://pjax.herokuapp.com/) does the same :)